# Posting to mongoDb with ObjectId Many to one relationship

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, axios

Mongoose/MongoDB Question

I have an Owners model containing basic profile data.

I have a secondary model: `OwnersImages`
e.g

```
    {
        owner: { 
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Owners'
        },
        name: String,
        imageUrl: String,
    },
);
```

From the client I want to post the imageUrl and the name to the OwnersImages table.
e.g

```
          let values = {
            owner: this.state.user._id,
            name: this.state.field,
            imageUrl: this.state.url
          }
          axios.post(`${serverPath}/api/addFieldImage`, values)
```

However Im unsure how best to go about this, link it etc.

I can do a GET request on the `Owners` table to get the `Owner` data, but then posting this as part of the values to `OwnerImages` doesn't successfully link the two tables.

Do i need to just store a string reference to the Owner id in `OwnerImages` or is there a smarter way of doing this?

Or should I just post the string of the user Id to mongoose and then do a map to the Owner table from within there?

Tried to explain this best way I could but the eyes are tired so please ask if any confusion!
Many thanks

Comment: Did you try to look at `$lookup` an aggregation operator that `JOINS` two collections ?

Comment: Can you explain better what is `OwnerImages`? is this another schema? what is the difference between `OwnerImages` and `Owners`?

Comment: `Owners` is a model of users and `OwnerImages` is a model of uploaded images that link to an owner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing your exact setup, I think you could modify this to fit your needs:

```
// In the Schema/Model files
const ownersSchema = Schema({
  // other fields above...
  images: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'OwnersImages' }]
});

const ownersImagesSchema = Schema({
  // other fields above...
  owner: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Owners' },
});


// in the route-handler
Owners.findById(req.body.owner, async (err, owner) => {
  const ownersImage = new OwnersImages(req.body);
  owner.images.push(ownersImage._id);
  await ownersImage.save();
  await owner.save();
});
```

As a side-note, I think the Models generally have singular names, so Owner and OwnerImage. The collection will then automatically take on the plural form. Just food for thought.

When you want to load these, you can link them with `populate()`. Consider loading all of the `OwnersImages` associated with an `Owners` in some route-handler where the `/:id` param is the `Owners` id:

```
Owners
  .findOne({ _id: req.params.id })
  .populate('images')
  .exec(function (err, images) {
    if (err) return handleError(err);
    // do something with the images...
  });
```

Comment: Thank you Daniel this helps a lot!